# Retrieve all documents version list in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Need to fetch list of all documents version.

Is there a way to do this with SQL.

Also , In a folder , can we find which subfolders have versioned documents in them ?

Thanks

Comment: Using the alfresco API (REST/CMIS) is not wanted ?

Comment: i have never used that .... I am more familiar with SQL
Can you please tell the steps 
Thanks

Comment: You should have a look at the alfresco documentation : http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/RESTful-intro.html. In my opinion, you shouldn't query directly the alfresco database

Comment: the below url gives me all versions for a single document

/alfresco/service/api/version?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/ab015fa6-3cb5-4cc3-9847-9c79e9da0d56


how to get all versions for all documents inside a particular folder

Comment: using webscript easily you can get all the version of document of given folder.